# Java - using method in browser.execute(script)

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, swt

I have a method with an array that contains names, I am using SWT Browser and with `browser.execute()` I want to fill the form.

My question:
I want to use the `generateName()` method in the `browser.execute()` part instead of TEST as value.

Method

```
/**
 * generate name, lastname
 */
public void generateName() {
   Random generateName = new Random();
   String[] name = {"Liam", "Elias", "Kevin", "Julian", "Linus", "Levi", "Jonas", "Daniel", "Milan", "Maria", "Alexander", "Manfred", "Max", "Jens", "Dennis", "Oliver", "Jan", "Bob", "Henry"};
   String[] lastname = {"Meyer", "Müller", "Eilers", "Gerdes", "Schröder", "Janssen", "Ahlers", "Bruns", "Behrens", "Harms", "Schmidt", "Macke", "Kruse", "Becker", "Lange", "Suhr", "Schulte", "Weber", "Lampe"};

   // debug
   System.out.println(name[generateName.nextInt(19)] + " " + lastname[generateName.nextInt(19)]);
}
```

Button with listner

```
/**
 * Create contents of the window.
 */
protected void createContents() {
    shell = new Shell();
    shell.setSize(800, 600);
    shell.setText("SWT Application");

    Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
    browser.setUrl("www.pseudopage.com/SignUp");
    browser.setBounds(10, 10, 780, 352);

    Button btnNewButton = new Button(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    btnNewButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            browser.execute("document.getElementById('txtFirstName').value=\"TEST\"");
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(10, 374, 94, 28);
    btnNewButton.setText("Generate");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your question.. So let's hope I have:

you could:

```
browser.execute("document.getElementById('txtFirstName').value=\"" + generateName() + "\"");
```

but generateName must return a value instead of printing it..

```
public String generateName() {
   Random generateName = new Random();
   String[] name = ...
   String[] lastname = ...

   return name[generateName.nextInt(19)] + " " + lastname[generateName.nextInt(19)];
}
```

Comment: That worked!
changed the method to String instead of void and the return of course.

Thank you!